# Execute commands from a remote path

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

When we execute i.e. `ls` command the terminal application search for that `ls` on our `PATH` variable. The `PATH` usually contains a number of system directories plus some user specific directories. So a command might be searched first on the user directories and if not found then it will be looked under system directories.

Would it be possible to add a remote path (from the network/internet) to `PATH`? So commands could be seached and retrieved from i.e 192.168.1.100 or equivalent name.

I would like to define `mycommand` on a (let me call it) command server and then go to another machine in the network and type:

```
PATH = 192.168.1.100:PATH
mycommand
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to add a remote path (from the network/Internet) to `PATH`?

No, not directly. Proper `PATH` specifies directories available in the file hierarchy. Still there's a general way to bring a remote file (here `mycommand`) to the hierarchy:

1. Let the sever share `mycommand` (or possibly/probably some directory tree that contains `mycommand`) using some protocol (e.g. NFS).
2. Mount the relevant share on the other machine, so `mycommand` appears in *its* file hierarchy as if it was a local file. Do not use `noexec`, you can explicitly use `exec` (see `man 8 mount`). In general some protocols/tools/solutions may not allow files to be executable though.
3. Adjust `PATH` there: add a pathname leading to the directory that contains `mycommand` that *appears* local.

Notes:

- If `mycommand` is a binary executable, it may not work because of mismatching architecture or kernel.
- Any pathname used by `mycommand` will be resolved locally. In particular the shebang (if any).
- If `mycommand` requires other files, it may use local files; this may not be what you want.
- If `mycommand` should use other files (e.g. libraries) existing on the server, it may not be easy to get them. If you get them from the server, it may not be easy to actually use them. For libraries, I think in some cases `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD` can help (depending on the executable); research these.
- Network problems may cause… problems ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/308748/108618)); even an otherwise normal delay may turn out to be a problem. Note you may experience problems whenever the relevant directory from `PATH` is examined, this may happen even when invoking something other than `mycommand`.
- Usually root access is required to mount anything. There are ways to allow a regular user to mount, they require at least one-time assistance from the root user (e.g. editing `/etc/fstab`, editing `/etc/sudoers`, installing [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)).

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you think about it, the PATH assumes a filesystem. Once you start putting other things in it you no longer have a filesystem, and need to work out the protocol to access the resource which is not standard. It would also greatly slow access to any scripts/commands that look through the path, to the point it may become unbearable.

A work arround might be to graft the exposed network resource into the filesystem. How you would do this is dependent on protocol and OS.